# How to extract information from page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the `name` and `phone number` from this page

```
from selenium import webdriver
# location of chromedriver.exe
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://www.houzz.com/professionals/general-contractor")

for title in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="mlm header-5 text-unbold"]'):
    title.click()
    name=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//h1[@class="mwxddt-0 jIujVr"]')
    print(name)
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: I am trying to extract name and phone number they show these  error `Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a loop for this case, look for name by index and then increase index by 1 for every iteration.

Also, you should scroll to each element to let selenium know that elements are in their view port.

**Code :**

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")

browser.maximize_window()
browser.implicitly_wait(30)

browser.get("https://www.houzz.com/professionals/general-contractor")
size = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@itemprop='name']")
j = 1
for i in range(len(size)):
    element =  browser.find_element(By.XPATH, f"(//span[@itemprop='name'])[{j}]")
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    print(element.text)
    j = j +1
```

**Output :**

```
Capital Remodeling
SOD Home Group
Innovative Construction Inc.
Baron Construction & Remodeling Co.
Luxe Remodel
California Home Builders & Remodeling Inc.
Sneller Custom Homes and Remodeling, LLC
123 Remodeling Inc.
Professional builders & Remodeling, Inc
Rudloff Custom Builders
LAR Construction & Remodeling
Erie Construction Mid West
Regal Construction & Remodeling Inc.
Mr. & Mrs. Construction & Remodeling
Bailey Remodeling and Construction LLC
```

**Update 1 :**

```
browser= webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
browser.get("https://www.houzz.com/professionals/general-contractor")
size = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@itemprop='name']")
j = 1
for i in range(len(size)):
    element =  browser.find_element(By.XPATH, f"(//span[@itemprop='name'])[{j}]")
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    print(element.text)
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-component='Pro Phone Link']"))).click()
    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-component='Call Pro']"))).text)
    #wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Website"))).click()
    browser.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    j = j + 1
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: THANKS it also work for me but I want that he `click` on every tilte and go inside every product and then collect the title

Comment: once you click on the title on first page, it will redirect to new page, what data you want to scrape from new page ?

Comment: collect `title`  `phone` number and `website`